# Creating CI and CD pipelines for Azure data factory with or without triggers

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-data-factory

When trying to configure a release pipeline for ADF getting an error as below :

```
Trigger enabled cannot update : Cannot update enabled trigger; trigger needs to be disabled first.
```

**But there are no triggers in ADF.**

How can this be handled ?

There are 3 steps in release pipeline

1. Disable triggers Azure power shell script

`$triggersADF | ForEach-Object { Stop-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -DataFactoryName <DataFactoryName> -Name $_.name -Force }`

2. ARM template deployment
3. Enable triggers Azure power shell script

`$triggersADF | ForEach-Object { Start-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -DataFactoryName <DataFactoryName> -Name $_.name -Force }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are already following the [sequence of deploy ADF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment#updating-active-triggers) as per MS docs.

I suspect that there is something unexpected in the ARM template. I would recommend you to [export the template manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/export-template-portal) and use it instead. Your scripts look fine.